Inverse and forward kinematics ignore last link in calculation
I have builded a 3 DOF robot arm irl and now I want to control the end effector with the help of inverse kinematics. I used urdf extansion to create a basic version my robot arm and I used Jupyter Lab to create a code for inverse kinematics thanks to ikpy.
When I check URDF Widget Factory, the robot arm construction looks fine. But when I run the code for inverse kinematics and plot the robot arm, I cannot see my last link.
Here is my urdf file:
<robot name="My Robot">
    
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.0225" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.050" radius="0.089"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="base_color">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <link name="base_to_link1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.05 0.05 0.074965" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="base_to_link1_color">
                <color rgba="0 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>
    
    <joint name="base_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="base_to_link1"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.0874825" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
      <limit lower="-3.1" upper="3.1" />
    </joint>
    
    <link name="link1">
        <visual>
          <origin xyz="0 0 0.1495" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.299" radius="0.022"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="link1_color">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>
    
    <joint name="second_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="base_to_link1"/>
      <child link="link1"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.0374825" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
      <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" />
    </joint>
    
    <link name="link2">
        <visual>
          <origin xyz="0 0 0.1495" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.299" radius="0.022"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="link2_color">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <joint name="third_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="link1"/>
      <child link="link2"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.299" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.92" upper="1.92" />
    </joint>
    
</robot>

And here is my Jupyter Notebook code:
import ikpy.chain
import ikpy.utils.plot as plot_utils

import numpy as np
import time
import math

import ipywidgets as widgets
import serial

my_chain = ikpy.chain.Chain.from_urdf_file("arm_urdf.urdf", active_links_mask=[False, True, True, True])

target_position = [ 0, 0, 0.722965]

ik = my_chain.inverse_kinematics(target_position)

computed_position = my_chain.forward_kinematics(ik)

%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plot_utils.init_3d_figure()
fig.set_figheight(9)  
fig.set_figwidth(13)  
my_chain.plot(ik, ax, target=target_position)
plt.xlim(-0.5, 0.5)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
plt.ion()

Here is the URDF Widget Factory:
URDF Widget Factory
Here is the output of the graph:
Graph From the Code
I believe the problem lies with my urdf file and I tried to check the documents about how to create a model but I cannot find my mistake.

I spent more time working on this issue, and I wanted to share my solution in case anyone else gets stuck on the same problem.
It seems that the last link is always ignored in the process (or at least, I couldn't find another way to fix this). When I added an end-effector (just a simple sphere), it was also ignored since it was the last "link" that is created, while the remaining links were taken into account both in calculation and graph.
So, I just added an end-effector and set it as a fixed joint (fixed because it's just a solid connection between two parts) between itself and the last link (link2). With this setup, the inverse kinematics function in IKPy now works perfectly!
Here is the new urdf file with an end-effector:
<robot name="My Robot">

<material name="red">
    <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
</material>

<material name="green">
    <color rgba="0 1 0 1"/>
</material>

<material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
</material>

<material name="yellow">
    <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
</material>

<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.089"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="red">
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="base_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="base_to_link1"/>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
  <limit lower="-3.1" upper="3.1" />
</joint>

<link name="base_to_link1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.0374825" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.05 0.05 0.074965" />
        </geometry>
        <material name="green">
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="second_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent link="base_to_link1"/>
  <child link="link1"/>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0.074965" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" />
</joint>

<link name="link1">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.1495" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.299" radius="0.022"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="blue">
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="third_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent link="link1"/>
  <child link="link2"/>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0.299" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.92" upper="1.92" />
</joint>

<link name="link2">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.1495" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.299" radius="0.022"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="yellow">
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="link2_to_endeffector" type="fixed">
  <parent link="link2"/>
  <child link="endeffector"/>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0.299" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="endeffector">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.022"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="red">
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>
</robot>

Don't forget to edit the active_links_mask in the main code! Now we have one more link (end-effector) and it is a fixed link!
my_chain = ikpy.chain.Chain.from_urdf_file("arm_urdf.urdf", active_links_mask=[False, True, True, True, False])

Finally, here is the result of the graph!

